# Getting at water heater anode AO Smith ECT40-200

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I found this [spec sheet](http://www.hotwater.com/lit/spec/res_elec/aosre50300.pdf) for my water heater which shows where the anode is.  However I'm not so sure which of two ports is the anode.  Here's a picture.

[image]

In the spec sheet diagram it seems the anode is at the green circle but that's the PRV so what gives?

I know I shouldn't ask what this is but I'll include it in case it relates to the main question.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the T&P valve is plumbed in where the anode rod should be, and the hole where the T&P valve should be, is simply plugged.

Comment: Looked through some documentation, and it does say that the T&P valve can optionally be installed on the top of some units. However, it does not mention where the anode is, when the T&P is on top.

Comment: @Tester101 that's what I was thinking.  I have no idea why they did that.

Comment: The [installation manual's Repair Parts List](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7On8c.png), shows a secondary anode on the hot water outlet.  So possibly, you'll have to remove the hot water line to access it.  I might contact the manufacturer, and ask them before attempting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anode rod was under the hot water pipe.  Getting the water heater nipple off was tough (to say the least) I bought some black pipe and a 90.  I drilled a hole through the nipple and the 90 and put a thick (forgot what size) bolt through and used the pipe as a really long breaker bar.  (You're going to need new bits for this. I wasted an absurd amount of time drilling with old ass bits making literally no progress before I bought some new bits which cut through like butter) With that setup I got it about an eighth of a turn which was enough to switch to a pipe wrench and channel locks.  I put the new anode rod where the t&p valve was and put the t&p valve on the front.